# Vector push_back error when compiling

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Compiling this segment of code involving using the push_back function for vectors ends up in an error.

```
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        Profit[i].push_back(0);
        Weight[i].push_back(0);
        Name[i].push_back("");
    }
    else
    {
        Profit[i].push_back(tosteal[i-1].getProfit());
        Weight[i].push_back(tosteal[i-1].getWeight());
        Name[i].push_back(tosteal[i-1].getName());
    }   
}
```

Weight and Profit are declared vectors of the int data type and Name is a vector of the string data type. tosteal is an array of items objects. getProfit() and getWeight() return an int and getName() returns a string.

These are the errors the compiler gives, some are repeats:

```
167: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘Profit.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](((long unsigned int)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘int’

168: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘Weight.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](((long unsigned int)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘int’

169: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’

169: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::push_back(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’

173: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘Profit.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](((long unsigned int)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘int’

174: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘Weight.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](((long unsigned int)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘int’

175: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::push_back(std::string)’
 note: candidates are: void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::push_back(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
```

Comment: Not what you ask, but the range of `i` in `for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)` does not feel right.

Comment: _Weight and Profit are declared vectors of the int data type_...ok so why do you need to do `Weight[i].push_back`?

Answer (score 7):

```
Profit[i].push_back(0);
```

Should be

```
Profit.push_back(0);
```

And so on. `Profit` is the vector itself; by saying `Profit[i].push_back(0)`, you are trying to push something into one of the elements that is already in the vector, rather than pushing something into the vector.

Since the element type is `int`, `Profit[i]` is of type `int`, which is why you get the error: `request for member ‘push_back’ in [...] which is of non-class type ‘int’`.